# Database module abstract (independent) from other modules of the game

Tags: c++, database, module, dependencies

I have a game that consists of few modules.

One of them is database module.
I want to make it something like that:

```
Database{
    public:
        save(&Object); //all my classes in the all modules inherit from Object
        load(&Object);
};
```

What would be the best way to make that module **independent from other modules** (other modules will store data in `Database` using `save` and `load` functions)?

**I consider few solutions:**

1. All objects have something like `serialize()` method that is inherited from `Object` class (analogy to Java). `Database` use that method to get the string and save it. Obvious disadvantages are: all objects have to implement new method and it won't be optimum to save strings (not knowing about the classes' structure).
2. Make 'manifests' for all the classes (in e.g. text file that will be send to `Database`). That manifests will describe what the structure of class is (e.g. one string, two double, one rare use int). Disadvantage is flexibility - changing the classes in other modules will have affect on manifests.
3. All classes has own `save` and `load` methods and `Database` use them. I don't want it, because all classes would have to know about database type and `save` and `load` should be in `Database` class, not distributed in the whole code (it's a main point to make such a module).
4. `Database` knows about all other modules (and will know how to save all objects). Bad thing here is a lot of dependencies. Changes in any of modules will affect the `Database`.

Which way will be good? Or maybe there's a better option?

Comment: When you talk about a serialize() method it sounds like you want to use a name value store (ala NoSQL).  Usually a database would store one value per column in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I've come across is to have all Object subclasses implement a `virtual void serialize(ISerializer& serializer)` method.

*ISerializer* would have pure virtual methods like `void onInt(int value)`, `void onString(const char* string)` etc to be called by the Object subclass inside its `serialize()`-method.  Your Database module could implement *ISerializer* in two separate classes, *DatabaseReader* and *DatabaseWriter*.  Later on you could add *ObjectInspectionFileDumper*, *OnScreenObjectStateDebugger* or *NetworkWriter* that also implement *ISerializer*, but in other modules.  Each object only needs to implement the `serialize()`-method once to gain all those possibilities for extension.

Pros:

- Reading and writing is pretty much guaranteed to match up as long as you don't read data for an old version of an object without some kind of versioning scheme on top.
- This is an orthogonal design, where the number of Object types and Serializer types can grow independently of each other.

Cons:

- Mainly some virtual function overhead, if that is an issue for your project.  This isn't something you will typically be doing much during regular gameplay though.

Later, you might come across things you want to call Objects which you don't want to serialize, then it could make sense to separate that out into an *ISerializable* interface class, only containing the pure virtual `serialize()`-method.  To accommodate serializers where it matters (like debug serializers), you might want to change to `void onInt(const char* name, int value)` etc instead.

HTH